# Screen Capture rendered on a RenderTexture in Unity

Tags: unity, rendering, screen, rendertexture, streaming

I have a pretty wild idea for a unity application that would work on a multi-display setup.

The app would be running in full screen mode on one of my displays, and the contents of the remaining two displays should be rendered in-game on a texture.

I've seen RTMP clients for unity and I've tried streaming my desktop with OBS to a local RTMP server but the delay was too big (more than 5 seconds). I would prefer an instant (or very low delay) solution for mirroring my displays on textures in Unity.

If anyone can help me solve this, i would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I found one possible solution, but I haven't had time to try it. I will make a separate program that captures screenshots at around 30 FPS using DirectX (SharpDX) and these frames will be pumped into some sort of Socket (UDP or TCP) and a separate thread in Unity will receive and decode them and turn them into a Texture.