# How to Share Screen in Unity

Tags: unity, unity-networking

I am trying to create a virtual workspace where one user can share his computer screen (and show what other Desktop applications are running) onto an in-game screen in unity. By researching I did not find any way to achieve this. Is it possible in unity?

Comment: So you want your Unity game to stream the client's desktop to other users game client?

Comment: You may be interested in [Screen capture rendered on a RenderTexture in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/159593/39518)

Comment: A search for [Unity capture desktop](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+capture+desktop&ia=web) and [Unity desktop duplication](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+desktop+duplication&ia=web) also turns up a lot of promising links [like this one](https://github.com/hecomi/uDesktopDuplication). Did you try these methods? Where specifically did you encounter difficulty solving the problem with these?